# How to extract part of association?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, associations

Considering an association:

```
asc = <|"a"->1, "b"->2, "c"-><|"e"->3, "c"->4|>, "d"->5, "e"->6, "f"-><|"g"->7|>|>
```

How to extract `"c"` and `"f"` from `asc` to have :

```
ascNew =  <|"a"->1, "b"->2, "d"->5, "e"->6|>
estracted =  <|"c"-><|"e"->3, "c"->4|>, "f"-><|"g"->7|>|>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Through[{KeyDrop, KeyTake}[asc, {"c", "f"}]]
```